# Definitions for CMMI Requirement Types in TFS2010

Tags: tfs, requirements, cmmi

I've recently been informed that I need to define the requirements for the project I'm working on using TFS and CMMI. Upon writing a new requirement, you must supply a "Requirement Type". My question is, where can I find actual definitions of the different requirement types? Yes, of course I have googled this already and have found some glossaries that are closely aligned, but not perfect.

If any of you out there have experience with CMMI, and can define these types or point to a better source of information, I would be greatly thankful.

To make this easier, the CMMI requirement types are listed (in TFS) as:

- Business Objective
- Feature
- Functional
- Interface
- Operational
- Quality of Service
- Safety
- Scenario
- Security

Comment: See [MSF for CMMI Process Improvement v5.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997574.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, I had read through the MSDN article and it does not give any definitions of the CMMI Requirement types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specific interpretation you place on the Requirement Type values will depend on your organization but a consistent interpretation of the values is the key thing. Pick a definition and stick to it.

TFS can capture and store the data for later reporting through any of the available reporting mechanisms.

Functionally the field is used in the following manner:

- The "Customer Requirements" team query includes requirements with a "Quality of Service" or "Scenario" type
- The "Product Requirements" team query includes requirements with a "Functional", "Interface", "Operational", "Security", "Safety" or "Feature" type
- The "Work Breakdown" query includes the field in its results
- The field is marked as reportable and will appear in the Team Foundation Analysis Services cube so it is available for including in your reports
- It's available as one of the fields in MS Project

Comment: I confuse with safety and security, could you please to explain it?